# Program failed for outputting brute force results on decryption method

Tags: python, encryption

```
def asciiShift(character, aShift):
  asciiNum = ord(character) + (int(aShift))%26
  return asciiNum

def stringShift(string, shift):
  k=0
  newstring = ''
  string_len = len(string)
  while k<string_len:
    newstring = newstring + string[int(((int(shift)%int(string_len))+k))%int(string_len)]
    k=k+1
    if k==string_len:
      break
  return newstring
  

def encrypt(message, aShift, sShift):
  i=0
  length = len(message)
  asciiChars = []
  while i<length:
    asciiChars.append(asciiShift(message[i].upper(), aShift))
    i=i+1
    if i==length:
      break
  string = ''
  j=0
  while j<length:
    string = string + str(chr(asciiChars[j]))
    j=j+1
  shifted_string = stringShift(string, sShift)
  print(shifted_string)

def decrypt(message):
  x=0
  mlength = len(message)
  mstring = ''
  while x<mlength:
    d=0
    while d<mlength:
      mstring = mstring + message[int(x+d)%(mlength)]
      d=d+1
    e=0
    mstring = mstring.upper()
    mlist = []
    while e<mlength:
      mlist.append(ord(mstring[e]))
      e=e+1
    f=0
    while f<26:
      g=0
      newstring = ''
      while g<mlength:
        newstring = newstring + chr(mlist[g] + f%26)
        g=g+1
      print(newstring)
      f=f+1
    x=x+1
    if x==mlength:
      break

  # todo list
  # shift string around (use.upper())
  # convert shifted string to ascii number list
  # add numbers from 0-25 to the ascii number list
  # print out the results
  


typeConfirm = input("Encrypt or Decrypt? (E/D): ")
if typeConfirm[0].upper() == 'D':
  decryptBool = True
elif typeConfirm[0].upper()== 'E':
  decryptBool = False
else:
  print("You probably said an incorrect choice or read the question incorrectly. Exiting program for now...")
  exit()

if decryptBool == True:
  decrypt_msg = input("What is the encoded message?: ")
  decrypt(decrypt_msg)
else:
  message = input("What is your message?: ")
  aShift = input("ASCII shift?: ")
  sShift = input("String shift?: ")
  
  a=0
  b=len(message)
  while a<b:
    if message[a] == '~':
      print("Sorry, the encryptor doesn't support any special characters (other than the ones on a normal keyboard, or these characters that are on a keyboard: '~', '{', and '}' only these 3 characters in the quotation marks don't work. Sorry for the inconvenience!")
      exit()
    elif message[a] == '{':
      print("Sorry, the encryptor doesn't support any special characters (other than the ones on a normal keyboard, or these characters that are on a keyboard: '~', '{', and '}' only these 3 characters in the quotation marks don't work. Sorry for the inconvenience!")
      exit()
    elif message[a] == '}':
      print("Sorry, the encryptor doesn't support any special characters that aren't on a normal office keyboard. However, these characters that are on a keyboard don't work: '~', '{', and '}' only these 3 characters in the quotation marks don't work. Sorry for the inconvenience!")
      exit()
    a=a+1
    if a==b:
      break
  encrypt(message, aShift, sShift)
```

I made this code so far, however for some reason, the decrypter doesn't work with the outputs of the encrypter. (As in, the brute force doesn't output the input at all)

For context, the purpose of this program would be to encrypt a string by converting all the characters to ascii code, and adding a number to it. Then, the new number would be turned back into a character, and the string would be shifted by a certain amount. For ex, "ABC" shift 1 -> [66, 67, 68] -> "BCD" shift 2 -> "DBC"

If someone could help point out why it isn't working (or if there's a better solution, ex. "you wrote this area wrong", or "the encryptor result is faulty", etc.), it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just curious.  How come there is no prompting for an ASCII shift value and string shift value when asking to decrypt?  Is there supposed to be something inherently deduced from the encrypted message that allows the program to calculate the string shift and ASCII shift values and then apply them?

Comment: No, it's a brute force method. The while loops are really messy, so I probably failed something without noticing...

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated you just want to start out with performing a brute force algorithm to decrypt an encrypted phrase or word, the intuitive solution seemed to be to create complimentary functions for the ASCII shift and string shift functions that perform a shift in the opposite direction for the decryption function.  Then, build the decryption function such that it is almost a duplicate of the encryption function except it loops through the possible shifting utilizing the complimentary functions.

Following is a revised version of your code you can experiment with.

```
def asciiShift(character, aShift):
  asciiNum = ord(character) + (int(aShift))%26
  return asciiNum
  
def asciiShiftx(character, aShift):
  asciiNum = ord(character) - (int(aShift))%26
  return asciiNum 

def stringShift(string, shift):
  k=0
  newstring = ''
  string_len = len(string)
  while k<string_len:
    newstring = newstring + string[int(((int(shift)%int(string_len))+k))%int(string_len)]
    k=k+1
    if k==string_len:
      break
  return newstring
  
def stringShiftx(string, shift):
  k=0
  newstring = ''
  string_len = len(string)
  while k<string_len:
    newstring = newstring + string[int(((int(shift * -1)%int(string_len))+k))%int(string_len)]
    k=k+1
    if k==string_len:
      break
  return newstring

def encrypt(message, aShift, sShift):
  i=0
  length = len(message)
  asciiChars = []
  while i<length:
    asciiChars.append(asciiShift(message[i].upper(), aShift))
    i=i+1
    if i==length:
      break
  string = ''
  j=0
  while j<length:
    string = string + str(chr(asciiChars[j]))
    j=j+1
  shifted_string = stringShift(string, sShift)
  print(shifted_string)

def decrypt(message):
  for z1 in range(26):
    for z2 in range(26):
      i=0
      lengthx = len(message)
      asciiChars = []
      while i<lengthx:
        asciiChars.append(asciiShiftx(message[i].upper(), z1))
        i=i+1
        if i==lengthx:
          break
      string = ''
      j=0
      while j<lengthx:
        string = string + str(chr(asciiChars[j]))
        j=j+1
      shifted_string = stringShiftx(string, z2)
      print('ASCII shift: ', z1, 'String shift: ', z2, shifted_string)

typeConfirm = input("Encrypt or Decrypt? (E/D): ")
if typeConfirm[0].upper() == 'D':
  decryptBool = True
elif typeConfirm[0].upper()== 'E':
  decryptBool = False
else:
  print("You probably said an incorrect choice or read the question incorrectly. Exiting program for now...")
  exit()

if decryptBool == True:
  decrypt_msg = input("What is the encoded message?: ")
  decrypt(decrypt_msg)
else:
  message = input("What is your message?: ")
  aShift = input("ASCII shift?: ")
  sShift = input("String shift?: ")
  
  a=0
  b=len(message)
  while a<b:
    if message[a] == '~':
      print("Sorry, the encryptor doesn't support any special characters (other than the ones on a normal keyboard, or these characters that are on a keyboard: '~', '{', and '}' only these 3 characters in the quotation marks don't work. Sorry for the inconvenience!")
      exit()
    elif message[a] == '{':
      print("Sorry, the encryptor doesn't support any special characters (other than the ones on a normal keyboard, or these characters that are on a keyboard: '~', '{', and '}' only these 3 characters in the quotation marks don't work. Sorry for the inconvenience!")
      exit()
    elif message[a] == '}':
      print("Sorry, the encryptor doesn't support any special characters that aren't on a normal office keyboard. However, these characters that are on a keyboard don't work: '~', '{', and '}' only these 3 characters in the quotation marks don't work. Sorry for the inconvenience!")
      exit()
    a=a+1
    if a==b:
      break
  encrypt(message, aShift, sShift)
```

I tested this out by encrypting a short phrase ("HELLO THERE") with an ASCII shift of "4" and a string shift of "22".

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Encrypt$ python3 Encrypt.py 
Encrypt or Decrypt? (E/D): E
What is your message?: HELLO THERE
ASCII shift?: 4
String shift?: 22
LIPPS$XLIVI
```

Then, I called the program again and asked it to decrypt the encrypted phrase ("LIPPS$XLIVI").  I will skip to the portion of the terminal output where one can see the original text.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Encrypt$ python3 Encrypt.py 
Encrypt or Decrypt? (E/D): D
What is the encoded message?: LIPPS$XLIVI
. . .
ASCII shift:  4 String shift:  18 O THEREHELL
ASCII shift:  4 String shift:  19 LO THEREHEL
ASCII shift:  4 String shift:  20 LLO THEREHE
ASCII shift:  4 String shift:  21 ELLO THEREH
ASCII shift:  4 String shift:  22 HELLO THERE
ASCII shift:  4 String shift:  23 EHELLO THER
ASCII shift:  4 String shift:  24 REHELLO THE
ASCII shift:  4 String shift:  25 EREHELLO TH
```

As would make sense the complimentary shift values match the original shift values where one sees the correct decrypted phrase.

Anyway, experiment with that.  Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I’d assume that now I just need to do a loop between all the possible numbers I have to use for both functions, and I’ll do that.

Comment: You're welcome.  Go for it!

Comment: I may have found a problem to the code, and will probably adjust it, it's just that the string shifter decryption only goes from 1-26. Is this intentional? Because from my understanding of the code, it can't go further than 26 characters.

Comment: I think that 
`for z2 in range(len(message)+1):`
would work, however none of my tests are working...
For example, "TEST" seems to work, however "HELLOO" doesn't work, and "EXAMPLE" with a ASCII shift of 25, and String Shift of 5, doesn't work either. Do you think there is a correlation with these results, or a bug with the code?

Comment: Never mind, I found the flaw in the program. Using .upper() in line 55 to the string messes up the ASCII shifting since it .uppers() the whole program. I also changed the string shift from being multiplied by -1, but I'll play around with it.

Thank you so much!